# New terminal 'can't create temp file' no such file or directory?

Tags: ros, source, permissions

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Technically not a ROS problem, but a misconfiguration/permissions error with zsh.
When I create a new terminal I was warned that:

```
/opt/ros/lunar/etc/catkin/profile.d/10.ros.sh:12: can't create temp file for here document: no such file or directory
/opt/ros/lunar/etc/catkin/profile.d/99.roslisp.sh:4: can't create temp file for here document: no such file or directory
/etc/zsh/zshrc:439: can't create temp file for here document : no such file or directory
```

These are all to do with file creation, and I assume it's a permissions error
I created an empty catkin_ws and did a `catkin_make` but it doesn't seem to have done anything.

I'm running `Debian Stretch (9.0)`, `ROS Lunar`, `zsh` (I source the `setup.bash` in my .bashrc and the equivalent `setup.zsh` my zshrc.pre)

When I installed I followed the instructions to do `sudo rosdep init` then `rosdep update` without the sudo.

Opening up a new bash shell I get no errors and the environment variable`ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is populated, whereas using zsh the variable exists but has no value.

Any suggestions? I feel like I need to change the ownership of something...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266617/new-terminal-%27can%27t-create-temp-file%27-no-such-file-or-directory?/) by [oharleySie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31237/oharleysie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I searched for `can't create temp file for here document:` and found this file: https://github.com/serialoverflow/dotfiles/blob/master/tag-zsh-common/zshenv , which seems to suggest that zsh can't create a temporary file for some reason. Their solution is to set the TMPDIR environment variable, but in your case I suspect the permissions on your `/tmp` directory are wrong, or `/tmp` is missing completely.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oharleySie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31237/oharleysie/) on 2017-07-18**:
I had pointed my TMPDIR to a nonexistent folder, thanks for this!